# jQuery: how do i run a piece of code when a checkbox is checked by an other plugin

Tags: jquery, forms

I am working on a small checkbox replacement script, but i want to use this with a other script which allows mass toggle of checkboxes, so when the a checkbox is set to checked or un-checked my code have to be updated, i have tried to use the change() but this dont work if the attr of the checkbox get's changed. Is this an bug or is my code wrong or do have to use something else?

I have stripped down all of the code in the plugin to make sure that nothing is blocking it. I dont get any errors.

the code in the plugin:

```
$('input').change(function () {
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      // run some code
   }else{
      // run some code
   }
}).change();
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? 1.6 introduced http://api.jquery.com/prop/ which has details of the best way to access checked.

Comment: using 1.7, i have changed the code above, i did use the is instead of the attr. Even without the if statement the code doesn't run

Answer (score 1):

If the checkbox is generated dynamically you need to use live() or on() (which was introduced in jQuery 1.7)

As in:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').live('change',function () {
   if($(this).is(':checked')){ //I like it using this way
      // run some code
   }else{
      // run another code
   }
});
```

Edit: check this example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b9Kab/

Comment: To mass toggle checkboxes, you don't need another script. Editing my code with a jsfiddle URL with I think exactly what you need.

Comment: i already have buildt a mass toggle checkbox script ;) thanks:)

Comment: Until I see your whole code, I can't exactly see where the issue is / where it is conflicting. I just coded that to show that with this way they don't conflict. Did this work for you ?

Comment: this works, but only if i click on the checkbox, if you mass toggle the boxes it doesn't doe anything, and i need to run my code when one, or multiple checkboxes are selected/unselected by some other code. The code above is all the code ;)

Comment: Well then you need to embed it into your own "mass-checker" script, which you did not provide. I created an event handler on my code, in which you can add any code after mass selection/deselection is done. e.g click here: http://jsfiddle.net/b9Kab/1/ After mass check is clicked, I check them all and alert a message. You can do anything else. Also if you want only to mass-check specific checkboxes, group them with rel attribute or another thing. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b9Kab/5/

Comment: yeah i think that i have to merge my two scripts, otherwise it wont work. Thanks for the help !!

Comment: Indeed, because its handler is in that that script's html, not this one. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `.attr()`

Check http://api.jquery.com/prop/, in particular:

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

So you should use: `$(this).prop('checked')`
pre 1.6 you should use: `$(this).is(":checked")`

Comment: yes i know, i normaly use the is......but i have changed this some reason...my bad

Comment: Did this fix the issue? Or is the change handler not running at all?

Comment: What's the result of `$('input')` when the script is initially running and registering the handler?

Comment: So when this code is called (when the script is loaded to the page?), you're selecting all the inputs and binding that anonymous function to the change event for them. Are you selecting all the right elements at that time? If not, you'll need to use `.live()` as per @Arda's answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5241/discussion-between-stuperuser-and-user759235)